# Can I run two 72" 7.2amp 240V baseboard heating units on one 12-3 wire supply

Tags: wiring

I would like to add two Baseboard heating units at my cottage under the front 8' windows. Is it possible and safe to run one 12-3 wire as supply? Looking at Cadet 72" units at 208V and 7.2 amps. should I use one thermostat or one on each unit?

Comment: 240V but 208V heaters? Are the heaters not rated for 240V? if they are, is it at a higher current than for 208V? If not, why would you even consider using them if your service is 240V????

Comment: They have 208V and 240V models. The 240V are more efficient at 6.3V for 240 and 5.4V for 208V. Should I just pay a little more and go with the 240V at the same 1500W?

Comment: The efficiency is **exactly the same** - 100% for any resistive electric heater. The 240/208v heater draws more current at 240V because it makes more heat at 240V than at 208V. You must NOT attach a 208V (only) heater to your 240V service, so you do need to buy a heater rated for 240V, or 240 **and** 208 regardless of the price of the 208V (only) heater (and I begin to think you should hire an electrician...)

Answer (score 3):

12Ga wire is rated for 20 amps, so derating for continuous load nets you 16 amps, [16Amps times 125% = 20 amps] and 14.4 amps is less than 16 amps, so one 12Ga wire should be adequate for two heaters.

Whether the thermostat is rated for that load will depend on the thermostat, but from a wiring point of view 12Ga wire is adequate.

Pending your response to comment, I'd expect a resistive heater that draws 7.2 amps on 208 volts to draw ~8.3 amps on 240V, at which point one 12Ga wire **won't** run two (but each could be run on a dedicated 14Ga wire, which is good for 12A continuous load.)

From comment to the question: Examining the 240/208V 72" heater, Part #: 09956

- Watts at 240V: 1500  - Amps at 240V: 6.3
- Watts at 208V: 1125  - Amps at 208V: 5.4

As expected, being a resistive device, when the Voltage goes up, the Current goes up, and the Power (which is also heat delivered) goes up. Running a 208V (only) heater on 240 V wil also result in more current, and more power, but will **probably also cause the heater to overheat**, as it is not designed to deliver that much power/heat.

Comment: Usually the amperage stays the same even with the voltage changing from 208 to 240.

Comment: @mikeytown2 A: Nonsensical. V=IR is not just a good idea, it's Ohm's law. B: not according to Cadet's website. Scroll down to see the 208/240V models. http://cadetheat.com/products/baseboard-heaters/baseboard

Comment: @mikeytown2 when comparing two products in a line card, yes, sometimes the 240 and 208 models will draw the same current. however, the 240 model in that case will have a smaller heating element. in the product in question here, this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up :) Note to self - use this more in the future: http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/ohms_law_calculator.php